# How to use apostrophes for repeated possessives?

Tags: possessives, apostrophe

As I get older I become more pedantic.  I recently wanted to write a message explaining my dread of going to weddings of children of my friends.

Which of the following is correct:

> I am dreading going to my friends' children's weddings.

or

> I am dreading going to my friend's children's weddings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand, you are talking about multiple friends with children, so the first one is correct, just an apostrophe after the plural. The second one would be correct if you were talking about one friend with children.

Comment: This is correct. Treat each word separately. Children of more than one friend: *friends'*. Children of one friend: *friend's*.